# Textedit right to left with mask

Tags: c#, devexpress, textedit

I have a TextEdit which hase a Mask.

`MaskType = Regular`

Edit mask: `\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?`

What i need is, that the input will be from right to left.

For example ('0' is the placeholder):

```
00000
00001
00012
00123
.....
```

until the max length is reached.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MaskType.Numeric` and `"00000"` for edit mask:

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "00000";
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.Numeric;
```